# Bazel googleapi gRPC cc_grpc_library output was not created

Tags: google-api, protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

I am running into Bazel build issues when I try to build googleapis texttospeech_proto and speech_proto with gRPC service. In the root directory of my project, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: <>/BUILD:42:1: output 'external/com_google_googleapis/google/cloud/texttospeech/v1/cloud_tts.grpc.pb.h' was not created
ERROR: <>/BUILD:42:1: output 'external/com_google_googleapis/google/cloud/texttospeech/v1/cloud_tts.grpc.pb.cc' was not created
ERROR: <>/BUILD:42:1: not all outputs were created or valid
```

My `BUILD`/`WORKSPACE` files are below:

#### BUILD

```
load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:cc_grpc_library.bzl", "cc_grpc_library")

cc_proto_library(
    name = "speech_cc_proto",
    deps = [
        "@com_google_googleapis//google/cloud/speech/v1p1beta1:speech_proto",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_grpc_library(
    name = "cloud_speech_grpc",
    srcs = [
        "@com_google_googleapis//google/cloud/speech/v1p1beta1:speech_proto",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":speech_cc_proto",
    ],
    grpc_only = 1,
    use_external = 1,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_proto_library(
    name = "texttospeech_cc_proto",
    deps = [
        "@com_google_googleapis//google/cloud/texttospeech/v1:texttospeech_proto",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_grpc_library(
    name = "cloud_texttospeech_grpc",
    srcs = [
        "@com_google_googleapis//google/cloud/texttospeech/v1:texttospeech_proto",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":texttospeech_cc_proto",
    ],
    grpc_only = 1,
    use_external = 1,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

#### WORKSPACE

```
git_repository(
    name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
    remote = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git",
    tag = "v1.27.0-pre1",
)
load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")
grpc_deps()

load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_extra_deps.bzl", "grpc_extra_deps")
grpc_extra_deps()

load("@io_bazel_rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_import", "pip_repositories")
pip_import(
    name = "grpc_python_dependencies",
    requirements = "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:requirements.bazel.txt",
)

load("@grpc_python_dependencies//:requirements.bzl", "pip_install")
pip_repositories()
pip_install()


git_repository(
    name = "com_google_googleapis",
    remote = "https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.git",
    commit = "3c39a1d6e23c1ef63c7fba4019c25e76c40dfe19",
)
load("@com_google_googleapis//:repository_rules.bzl", "switched_rules_by_language")
switched_rules_by_language(
    name = "com_google_googleapis_imports",
    cc = True,
    grpc = True,
)
```

If I move my `BUILD` file out of the root workspace (into a child workspace/folder), I receive a different error saying the `cloud_speech.proto` / `cloud_tts.proto` files are not within the child workspace.